# Merge two int in one double c# with Parse

Tags: c#, parsing, merge, int, double

i need to merge two int in one unique double.
my code and example:

```
int left = 1;
int right = 38;
```

i will wish get this result in double:

> double mergeVariable = 1.38

how is possible merge two int in one double ?

i have tried this but don't work

```
double result = double.Parse(left.ToString() + "." + right.ToString());
```

Thanks

Comment: As @DmitryBychenko pointed out, you even can use `left.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + right.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);` to work with current culture instead of invariant one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
  int left = 1;
  int right = 38;

  double result = double.Parse(
     left.ToString() + "." + right.ToString(),
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

in order **not** using current culture (which can have an *arbitrary decimal separator*, e.g. comma `,` as Russian has)

Answer (score 1):

You may be try with this approach and also getting the conversion result either conversion succeed to double or not.

```
try
{
    int left = 1;
    int right = 38;
    double Both;
    bool ConverstionSucceed = double.TryParse((left + "." + right), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out Both);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the integer into strings, combine this to strings and convert this to a double.

```
 left.toString();
 right.toString();
 string combinedLeftRight = left + "." + right;
 double mergeVariable = Convert.ToDouble(combinedLeftRight);
```

greetz

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble` in your code uses `Culture.CurrentCulture`; please, specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 0):

This would works too:

```
int left = 1;
int right = 38;

double result = left + right / Math.Pow(10, right.ToString().Length);
```

Comment: You want `Math.Pow`, not *multiplication*: if `right.Length == 2` you'll get `left + right / 20`

Answer (score 0):

This method will add decimal separator from current culture..

```
        int left = 1;
        int right = 38;

        double result = Convert.ToDouble(
           left.ToString() + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + right.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this answer: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484588/merge-two-int-in-one-double-c-sharp-with-parse/42484629#42484629)

Also the variant with the interpolated strings (if there is a possibility to use them) looks more concise:

```
int left = 1;
int right = 38;

double result = double.Parse($"{left}.{right}", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```